How to Optimize Memory Usage for Cross-Validation of Large Datasets
I have a very large DF (~200GB) of features that I want to perform cross validation on a random forest model with these features.
The features are from a huggingface model in the form of a .arrow file.
I am trying to figure out how I can minimize the amount of RAM needed to process this code-- even with 600GB of RAM, my code crashes.
I believe the issue is I am transforming from a huggingface dataset (https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/en/loading) to a pandas df to a numpy array (see the first 5 lines of code). I tried to figure out a way around this, but unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure it out.
If there are other ways to make my code more RAM efficient, please let me know.
# Load data
file_path = 'data.arrow' #200 GB in size

df = Dataset.from_file(file_path)   
df = df.data
df = df.to_pandas() 

X = np.array([np.array(x) for x in df['embeddings'].values])
y = df['label'].values
groups = df['Chromosome'].values
group_kfold = GroupKFold(n_splits=10)

# Initialize figure for plotting
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15, 6))

all_fpr = []
all_tpr = []
all_accuracy = []
all_pr_auc = []

best_score = 0
best_model = None

for i, (train_idx, val_idx) in enumerate(group_kfold.split(X, y, groups)):
    X_train_fold, X_val_fold = X[train_idx], X[val_idx]
    y_train_fold, y_val_fold = y[train_idx], y[val_idx]
    
    # Initialize classifier
    rf_classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=30, random_state=42, n_jobs=-1)
    
    # Train the classifier on this fold
    rf_classifier.fit(X_train_fold, y_train_fold)
    
    # Make predictions on the validation set
    y_pred_proba = rf_classifier.predict_proba(X_val_fold)[:, 1]

    # Calculate ROC curve
    fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_val_fold, y_pred_proba)
    all_fpr.append(fpr)
    all_tpr.append(tpr)
    roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr) #

    # Keep track of the best model based on ROC AUC
    if roc_auc > best_score:
        best_score = roc_auc
        best_model = rf_classifier

    # Plot ROC curve for this fold
    axes[0].plot(fpr, tpr, lw=1, alpha=0.7, label=f'ROC Fold {i+1} (AUC = {roc_auc:.2f})')
    
    # Calculate precision-recall curve
    precision, recall, _ = precision_recall_curve(y_val_fold, y_pred_proba)
    
    # Calculate PR AUC
    pr_auc = auc(recall, precision)
    all_pr_auc.append(pr_auc)

    # Plot PR curve for this fold
    axes[1].plot(recall, precision, lw=1, alpha=0.7, label=f'PR Curve Fold {i+1} (AUC = {pr_auc:.2f})')
    
    # Calculate accuracy
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_val_fold, rf_classifier.predict(X_val_fold))
    all_accuracy.append(accuracy)

# Save the best model
joblib.dump(best_model, 'model.pkl')


As the dataset you are using is for machine learning, do you really need to use all of the dataset? You could try taking a subset of the dataset, say maybe 2 million rows (or less); the model would most likely do just as well on those 2 million rows compared to on your whole dataset.
I don't know whether you are running on GPU or CPU, but if you by the way want it to run faster, you could run on GPU.
